# Prevent Location blue bar in ios 11

Tags: ios, core-location, ios11

As you already heard, in iOS11, an app that’s actively receiving continuous background updates will show a double-height blue bar, whenever authorization is set to While Using. It seems there is no way to remove the blue bar if the App is using background location App.
My app supports ios 9.0 and above and, I have added all the keys required in info.plist including the one below.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

But seems everybody says there is no way to remove the blue bar while background location updates is working.

However I have installed **UBER** and somehow they managed to hide the blue bar when the app is in background, but in my app I can see blue bar when I put app in background.

Does some one knows any solution to get rid of blue bar in iOS11 when we set permission "while using the app" ?

Comment: may be uber released this concept before ios11, now apple has modified this feature

Comment: If you only have "while using" permission then you should suspend location updates when your app moves to the background.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried your suggestion and it works. but if we go into settings app and change the mode always-> while using then the blue bar appears until we open the app. While UBER handles this as well and there is no blue bar when we do the same in UBER

Comment: Have you implemented the `didChangeAuthorization` delegate method in order to disable location updates if your app is in the background and you only have "when in use"?

Comment: Yes I have delegate methods implemented and when app goes into background I stopped location updates. and when in foreground I started location updates. But If I change the location settings from settings app I got the blue bar.However I've never seen blue bar in uber app with "while using the app" location permission.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 11, the Blue Bar will appear when an Always authorized app opts-in to displaying the blue bar while it is actively receiving Continuous Background Location updates via startUpdatingLocation()

There’s a new property on CLLocationManager that Always authorized apps can use to control the visibility of their blue bar.

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL showsBackgroundLocationIndicator
```

When-in-use authorized apps will continue showing the Blue Bar as before.

No other service will turn on the Blue Bar. When an app which makes use of any other location service receives an occasional update (for example Significant Location Change), the location arrow on the status bar will momentarily blink solid, but the Blue Bar will not appear.

Comment: I have already set this
@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL showsBackgroundLocationIndicator

to false

Comment: how we can get location updates in background when we have while using the app permission ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in `info.plist` file and use `requestAlwaysAuthorization`  in `CLLocationManager`.

[showsBackgroundLocationIndicator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/2923541-showsbackgroundlocationindicator) is useful for `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

Comment: Doing the same as you have stated, But ios 11 seems to have automatically shows while using and always options on alert

Answer (score 0):

According to apple , After iOS 11 update that blue bar is showing when app is running on the background. What you can do is, track user location when app is in the foreground. 
[Check this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/2923541-showsbackgroundlocationindicator)